# Add named function arguments automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, refactoring

I need to work with a number of classes that have big constructors (~20 parameters). Using visual studio 2015, is there a way to automatically add the parameter names next to the arguments? i.e.  A keyboard shortcut to change this:

```
new Thing(item1, item2, item3);
```

to this:

```
new Thing(param1: item1, param2: item2, param3: item3);
```

Comment: Resharper can do this..

Comment: Anyway, a constructor with 20 parameters? YOur class is definitly doing too much and needs strong refactoring. This way you won´t such tricks at all as all your classes depend only on a few other parameters.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I was waiting for that ;) Believe me, i know. Im stuck with it for now though